# Angular2 animation inside onInit does not work

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

In Angular2 app, i am trying to make an animation

Here is component's html:

```
   <div  [@playBox]="state" id="toPlay" class="playBox rounded-box">

   </div>
```

Here is the animation:

```
animations:[
    trigger('playBox',[
            state('closed',style({
            width: '5%',
            backgroundColor:'red',
            transform:'translateX(0)'
          })),
          state('wided',style({
                width: '100%',
                border: '3px solid red',
                backgroundColor:'transparent'
          })),transition('closed => wided',animate(4000))])
  ]
```

I am going to triger this animation when the page get loaded:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  state="closed";
 public ngOnInit(): any
 {

        if(this.state=="closed"){

            this.state="wided";
         }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the most proper and elegant solution but changing `state` in the next tick will trigger animation as expected:

```javascript
public ngOnInit(): any {
  if (this.state == "closed") {
    setTimeout(() => this.state = "wided")
  }
}
```

Otherwise, `this.state = "wided"` kind of redefines initial `closed` state and component gets initialized with `wided` as initial without animation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.state == "closed") {
    this.state = "wided";
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason, this worked exactly once for me, and since then the DOM is not reacting to changes of the state again.

Answer (score 0):

Please using:

```
transition('void => wided',animate(4000))])
```

the stage **void** mean when element not exists in DOM and then appears
About void state see [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#void-state)